# Cloud Code 'Invalid Function' when updating user object

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to update a user object, that is not the current user via useMasterKey. However, I get the error "invalid function" when running it. "blockedFrom" is an array in the user object that stores the list of users who blocked the concerned user and I am trying to add the usernames via addUniqueObject.

```
Parse.Cloud.job('addBlockedFrom', function(request, status) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", request.params.otherUser);  
    query.each(function(record) {
        record.addUniqueObject("blockedFrom", request.params.username);
        return record.save({useMasterKey:true});
    },{useMasterKey:true}).then(function(result) {
        console.log("addBlockedFrom completed.");
        status.success("addBlockedFrom completed.");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error in addBlockedFrom: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        status.error("Error in addBlockedFrom: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Add the full error. So we can see what type of error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing `Parse.Cloud.job` with `Parse.Cloud.define` as suggested by @TanzimChowdhury, I still had the invalid function error because of `status.success` and `status.error`. Status was undefined, replacing status with `response` fixed it.

**Working Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addBlockedFrom", function(request, response) { 
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);    
query.equalTo("username", request.params.otherUser);                                                                                     
query.each(function(user) {
      user.addUnique("blockedFrom", request.params.username);
      return user.save( null, { useMasterKey: true });
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    response.success("addBlockedFrom successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    response.error("Error addBlockedFrom.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is right , it's not a valid cloud code function.
What you defined above is a Job.
You need to define a cloud code function.

**Replace**

"*Parse.Cloud.job*" with "*Parse.Cloud.define*"

That should do the trick.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have parse server version >3 then your cloud code must be changed to new version.

Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addBlockedFrom", async (request) => {

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);    
  query.equalTo("username", request.params.otherUser); 
  try{
    var otherUser = await query.first();
    otherUser.addUnique("blockedFrom", request.params.username);
    return otherUser.save( null,{useMasterKey:true});
  }catch(err){
    throw err;
  }                                                                                    

});
```